# Hebrews 2:7 what is the meaning of "Thou madest him a little lower than angels"?

Tags: hebrews

Hebrews 2:7 KJV;

> 7. **Thou madest him a little lower than the angels**; Thou crownedst him with glory and honor, And didst set him over the works of thy hands:

What is the meaning of "Thou madest him a little lower than angels"?

Does this mean that He is essentially little somehow than angels, hence He is perfected?, Or He was made for a while little than angels?

Comment: You do realise this text is talking about Adam and not Jesus? Hebrews 2:6 "But somewhere it is testified in these words:

“What is man that You are mindful of him,"

Comment: Also read Genesis for a further explanation...Genesis1:28 God blessed them and said to them, “Be fruitful and multiply, and fill the earth and subdue it; rule over the fish of the sea and the birds of the air and every creature that crawls upon the earth.”

Comment: @adam how could it be, the verse is talking about Adam, not about Jesus?!

Comment: Because it says so in the first sentence. V6 starts off by saying..6"But somewhere it is testified in these words:"...Hebrews is quoting Genesis chapter 1. The bible often compares Adam as the first born of creation with the Son of Man (Jesus) as being the first born of God. This is why there is so much debate about the trinity.

Comment: @adam even if it was a quotation, it's a prophecy.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of this is Psalms 8:6 (8:5 in translations):
ותחסרהו מעט, מאלוהים  (*vateḥasrehu mé'at me-Elohim*)
— i.e., You made him a little lower than *God* – but that was considered too heretical a wording to translate verbatim.